# How to determined the angle of force weight in an incline force vector problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors

today in class I was introduced to some basic incline problems. I know that Force weight can be resolved into 2 components-the parallel and the perpendicular. I was given the angle of the ramp to be $30 degrees$. Which makes the parallel component to be $w *cos30$ and the perpendicular component to be $w * sin30$.  Now, this is the part of my question how do we know that the angle of the ramp (30) is equal to the angle of the force weight? Couldn't the angle in the force weight be a different angle? Why not? Thanks!

[image: orange is the angle, how can they be equal?]

Comment: How can the angle (coloured in orange) be the same?

Comment: The angle between any two lines is equal to the angle between their pependiculars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I hope this clears the confusion.  Use trigonometry to find the components of force.

Comment: woah @mechanic7 awesome thanks! i should have think of this before asking! thanks!